# Assembly code to binary convert question 'and, add'

Tags: assembly, mips

I do not understand converting Assembly code to binary.

For example I know that add `$d $s $t` goes to `00000ssssstttttddddd00000100000`, but how do I convert it to binary?

Also, how do I convert `and $f0 $f0 $0` to binary?

Comment: That **is** binary. What do you want to convert? Do you mean hex maybe?

Comment: Isn't s not a binary? And yes, I also need to convert it to hex

Comment: `sssss` are the 5 bits that code register $t number. So if `$t` is register #5 `sssss` are replaced by `00101` and it is the same for `$d` and `$t`. Concerning the coding of `and $f0 $f0 $0` you should precise which assembly you are using.